# Can a Shared Items Project have references to other Shared Items Projects?

Tags: visual-studio

I have 2 Shared Items Projects (c++ if that matters) in my solution, sipA and sipB. They are included in a Console App project, C. I now want sipB to reference sipA so that I can make use of some of the classes there, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Is it possible, or do I need to give up on Shared Items Projects for this use case?

Comment: Shared Items projects are merely file containers. I don't think you ever need to specify dependency relationship between such projects, as the compiler never verifies that (for instance, you compile a solution with two Shared Items projects and nothing should happen).

Comment: You are correct. When I later reopened the project and tried again everything compiled as expected, not sure what I'd managed to do wrong previously.